# how to save the data using state clinet in bots

Tags: bots, botframework

Hi I am on working bot project in that i am saving the present date like this(2016-09-23T18:38:41) format using StateClient in bot state service. Here i am facing issue when i am saving the date value using SetProperty() method its working fine but when i want to getting the value using GetProperty() method its giving the wrong date format like(1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM).
 For the above concept i wrote the below line of code in my project 
    enter code here

```
 var result = new ValidateResult { IsValid = true, Value = message.Text };
 DateTime? dt = DateTime.ParseExact(message.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy",      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (dt.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    await context.PostAsync("**Please enter a valid date like in the format DD/MM/YYY**" + " \r \n ");
                    result.IsValid = false;
                }
     else
      {
                    TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
                    dt = dt.Value.Date + ts;
                    d = dt.Value.Date + ts;
                    result.Value = dt;

      //saving the date format using SetProperty() using StateClient and BotData
                    BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(message.ChannelId, message.From.Id);
                    userData.SetProperty<DateTime?>("dt", dt);-->Here i am saving the date format like (2016-09-23T18:38:41)
                    await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(message.ChannelId, message.From.Id, userData);
                    await context.PostAsync("user message");
                }



     //Getting the data using GetProperty() using BotData
         BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync           (message.ChannelId, message.From.Id);
        var date= userData.GetProperty<DateTime>("dt");-->here i am getting the date format is like(1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM)
```

Please tel me what is the issue in my above code and how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most likely that you're not using a consistent (message.ChannelId, message.From.Id) across the user bot data bag GetUserDataAsync and SetUserDataAsync operations, and because DateTime is a value type, GetProperty is returning the default(DateTime) value.